# Suggestion for live video stream aggregation/switching/forwarding/management software?

Tags: video, streaming, live-broadcast

I'm looking for a software or system that can receive video streams from a number of cameras via a network (RTMP or similar protocol), present a visual overview of all video streams and allow me to forward/send a selected stream to another service (e.g. to a Flash Media Server, or anywhere via RTMP). Basically the digital internet equivalent of a TV studio control panel, which allows a director to put together a live show.

Is there any such software at an affordable price? A GUI-less server which can be scripted to switch streams would be good too.

I'm not even quite sure what kind of product category this falls into or what search terms to plug into Google. Most results I have come up with have little more than an executive summary description which doesn't tell me anything. Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: I hope you get some good answers, though I can't help pointing out the site dedicated to this topic that's trying to get off the ground http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production

Answer (score 0):

If you feeling a little ambitious, you could try writing your own [Red5](http://red5.org/wiki/Features) streaming application

Answer (score 0):

MythTV and its many plugins may offer what your looking for. I know it can do videochating in Kopete and such, but what it does beyond that, and how it does it is beyond me.